# design considerations of Ethernet-spi controller

Tags: pcb, ethernet, gsm

Recently I have designed  board on which Ethernet and gsm module need to be placed. Already I have exported Ethernet related chip to pcb and arranged in this order s shown in below image[image]

This is how I placed U10 (Ethernet-spi controller), U9(magnetics) ,J2 (RJ45).Whether this plcmnt is correct??
This complete board is consists 4layers.
Mid-Layer 1 will be power plane.
Mid- Layer 2 will be  ground plane.

One more GSM module need to be placed yet, where I don't have enough  place on top layer  except on below layer ...

My question is....
1.Shall I place gsm below this Ethernet setup..?

2.what are the pros & cons if I place in this Passion.

3. Is  there any  other  option to place?